# How to import or read an EPS (PostScript/Vector Format) to RStudio?

Tags: r, image, eps, digital

I have to import an EPS image format to R to convert it into a machine coded text. I tried using magick or grImport2/grImport but nothing seems to work. Only pdf/svg files can be read using `image_read` or `image_read_svg` or `image_read_pdf` functions.

Comment: can you use an external tool to convert EPS to PDF or will that cause a problem?

Comment: No external software to use, The algorithm must work solely in Rstudio. Here is the problem. https://imgur.com/tWFtINd